# Weird bug in trial code

Tags: java

This is some code I have been working on for a simple pub style quiz to learn Java. For some reason it will ask the question the first time and then will just skip past it from then on. It also declares the strings null even though I initialize them.

Here is the code

```
    public class PubQuizWMethod
    {
        private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        static String a1,a2,a3,a4;
        static String b1,b2,b3,b4;
        static String c1,c2,c3,c4;
        static String d1,d2,d3,d4;
        static String ans1,ans2,ans3,ans4;
        static String q1,q2,q3,q4;
        static String question;
        static boolean newQuiz = true;
        static boolean notStop = true;
        static char correctAnswer;
        static char answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4;
        static char answer;
        static int score = 0;

public static void mainMenu()
{
    {
        {
            do{
                gettingQuestion();
                question = q1;

                gettingAnswers();
                ans1 = a1;
                ans2 = b1;
                ans3 = c1;
                ans4 = d1;

                gettingCorrectAnswer();
                answer1 = correctAnswer;



                gettingQuestion();
                question = q2;

                gettingAnswers();
                ans1 = a2;
                ans2 = b2;
                ans3 = c2;
                ans4 = d2;

                gettingCorrectAnswer();
                answer2 = correctAnswer;




                gettingQuestion();
                question = q3;

                gettingAnswers();
                ans1 = a3;
                ans2 = b3;
                ans3 = c3;
                ans4 = d3;

                gettingCorrectAnswer();
                answer3 = correctAnswer;




                gettingQuestion();
                question = q4;
                ans1 = a4;
                ans2 = b4;
                ans3 = c4;
                ans4 = d4;

                gettingCorrectAnswer();
                answer4 = correctAnswer;



                if(notStop == true)
                {
                    score = 0;

                    System.out.println(q1);

                    System.out.println("a: " +a1);
                    System.out.println("b: " +b1);
                    System.out.println("c: " +c1);
                    System.out.println("d: " +d1);

                    answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

                    if(answer == answer1)
                    {
                        System.out.println("That was correct");
                        score ++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("That was incorrect");
                    }



                    System.out.println(q2);

                    System.out.println("a: " +a2);
                    System.out.println("b: " +b2);
                    System.out.println("c: " +c2);
                    System.out.println("d: " +d2);

                    answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

                    if(answer == answer2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("That was correct");
                        score ++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("That was incorrect");
                    }



                    System.out.println(q3);

                    System.out.println("a: " +a3);
                    System.out.println("b: " +b3);
                    System.out.println("c: " +c3);
                    System.out.println("d: " +d3);

                    answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

                    if(answer == answer3)
                    {
                        System.out.println("That was correct");
                        score ++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("That was incorrect");
                    }



                    System.out.println(q4);

                    System.out.println("a: " +a4);
                    System.out.println("b: " +b4);
                    System.out.println("c: " +c4);
                    System.out.println("d: " +d4);

                    answer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

                    if(answer == answer4)
                    {
                        System.out.println("That was correct");
                        score ++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("That was incorrect");
                    }

                    System.out.println("You achieved a score of " +score +" out of 4");
                    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?  y/n ");
                    char yn = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

                    if(yn == 'y')
                    {
                        notStop = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        notStop = false;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Would you like to make a new quiz? y/n");
                char yn = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
                if(yn == 'y')
                {
                    newQuiz = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    newQuiz = false;
                }

            }while(newQuiz = true);
        }
    }
}


public static void gettingQuestion()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the question");
    question = keyboard.nextLine();
}//getting the questions

public static void gettingAnswers()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter in the four answers each on its own line.");
    ans1 = keyboard.nextLine();
    ans2 = keyboard.nextLine();
    ans3 = keyboard.nextLine();
    ans4 = keyboard.nextLine();

}

public static void gettingCorrectAnswer()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the correct answer. a/b/c/d");
    correctAnswer = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    mainMenu();

}

}
```

and the result is this:

> ```
> Please enter the question
> ahsdf
> Please enter in the four answers each on its own line.
> adsfh
> adsfh
> asdfh
> asdfh
> Please enter the correct answer. a/b/c/d
> a
> Please enter the question
> Please enter in the four answers each on its own line.
> asdf
> asdfh
> asdfh
> asdfh
> Please enter the correct answer. a/b/c/d
> a
> Please enter the question
> Please enter in the four answers each on its own line.
> asdfh
> asdfh
> asdfh
> adsfh
> Please enter the correct answer. a/b/c/d
> asdfh
> Please enter the question
> Please enter the correct answer. a/b/c/d
> asdfh
> null
> a: null
> b: null
> c: null
> d: null
> a
> That was correct
> null
> a: null
> b: null
> c: null
> d: null
> a
> That was correct
> null
> a: null
> b: null
> c: null
> d: null
> a
> That was correct
> null
> a: null
> b: null
> c: null
> d: null
> a
> That was correct
> You achieved a score of 4 out of 4
> Would you like to play again?  y/n 
> y
> Would you like to make a new quiz? y/n
> n
> Please enter the question
> Please enter in the four answers each on its own line.
> ```

etc.

Comment: garbage in -> garbage out

Comment: Ahhh my eyes they burn. Ever heard of arrays?

Comment: `while(newQuiz = true)` This is always `true`.

Comment: yeah but as i have said I am learning java and thus haven't learn't how to use them yet.

Comment: but surely it is changed to false if you set it to that just above it?

Comment: It's a typo, @user2682894: `=` is an assignment, `==` is a comparison. `while(newQuiz = true)` will actually set newQuiz to true.

Comment: `Learning Java !=`... Uh I mean `!"Learning Java".equals("Doing lot of copy paste garbage")`. First do things small. And stop at the first error. And an SSCCE does a great service not only when asking a question, but when trying to tackle an error too...

Comment: Where do you actually assign values to `a1`, etc?

Comment: in the section just below the main menu

Comment: He is **NOT** using `==` to compare Strings!!

Comment: Ok Thanks. Everything has now been solved apart from when it goes to ask for the second question it still skips past it straight to the four answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pasted some of your code to explain what is happening. We start here:

```
public static void mainMenu()
{
    {
        {
            do{
                gettingQuestion(); 
                question = q1;
```

In the line below you are **reading from keyboard** and loading all values in **ans1, ans2, ans3 and ans4** variables.

```
                gettingAnswers();
```

Everything is ok, but when you do the following:

```
                ans1 = a1;
                ans2 = b1;
                ans3 = c1;
                ans4 = d1;
```

You are **overwriting** the ans1, ans2, ans3 and ans4 values, that's why you have **null** values.

As an extra note you can handle **arrays** or **objects** to keep your code with more order, it could be like this

```
public class Question{

private String realAnswer
private String question;
private String[] fakeAnswers = new String[4];

public Question(String realAnswer, String question, String [] fakeAnswers){
    this.realAnswer = realAnswer;
    this.question = question;
    this.fakeAnswers = fakeAnswers;
}

/*
   Some getters and setters
*/

}
```

Then you can create a **main** class that contains something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

// Number 10 is the quantity of questions that your quiz will have
Question[] question = new Question[10];

/*
More code
*/

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Classic mistake: Using `==` to compare `Strings` instead of `equals`.  It's not a bug; it's you and your code.

Comment: He didn't use `==` to compare Strings, those are `char`s what he's comparing.

Comment: ok thanks but what about where it seemed to ignore the input for all but the first of the times i used the gettingQuestion method

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `null` to `question` here.

```
gettingQuestion();
question = q1;    // q1 is null.
```

// Here question and q1 both are null and hence it is printing null in the answer.

Hence the output is printing null.

Also change the `while condition`.

Answer (score 1):

`next()` **doesn't** handle the end of the line. So when you call `nextLine()` again, it'll take as input the *enter* (`\n`) you entered before. So it's "*skipping*" the actual input and swallows the `\n` from the previous input that was missed by `next()`. You have two solutions:

- Call another `nextLine()` before the real `nextLine()` (So it will swallow the `\n`).
- Get rid of `next` and replace it with `nextLine()`.

Another thing:

The expression of the **assignment** returns the *assigned* value, look at this:

```
while(newQuiz = true);
```

What iside the `while` loop will be *always* `true`.

Also please note that it's redundant to write `if(variable == true)`, it's enough to write `if(variable)`.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Everything has now been solved apart from when it goes to ask for the second question it still skips past it straight to the four answers